# Do While Loop skipping statements 

Tags: java, arrays, static

In my do while loop, the body works fine initially, but when it loops, it prints the first two statements like it should but it does not allow me to enter the name instead it goes straight to enter pin and whatever I enter it skips the rest and asks me if I want another transaction.

I have an array object partially filed. The variables in the object are name, pin, account number and balance. When I add a new object and set the balance, the new balance I enter causes the balance for the previous objects to change as well. I think it has something to do with the balance variable being declared as static but I don't make it static, i can the error "Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method withdraw(double) from the type CustomerRecord". (SOLVED) Thank you.

```
public class BankCustomers 
{
public static void main(String[] args)

    //------------------------------------------------
    //Part4: Find a customer record from anotherArray 
    //to do transaction(s) and update the record's balance

    char repeat; // User control to repeat or quit
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in); //creating the scanner

    String aName;
    int aPin;
    double aWithdraw;
    double aDeposit;

    do{   


        //Read customer information before search
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Lets make a transaction");
        System.out.println("Enter customer full name");
        aName = keyboard.nextLine( );

        System.out.println("Enter Pin");
        aPin = keyboard.nextInt();


        //Search an Array for equal aName and aPin
        for (int i = 0; i < index; i++)
        {
            CustomerRecord cRecord = anotherArray[i];
                if((cRecord.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(aName)) && (cRecord.getPin()           ==(aPin)))
                {
                    System.out.println(cRecord);

                    System.out.println("Enter Withdraw Amount");
                    aWithdraw = keyboard.nextDouble();
                    CustomerRecord.withdraw(aWithdraw);

                    System.out.println("Enter Deposite Amount");
                    aDeposit = keyboard.nextDouble();
                    CustomerRecord.deposit(aDeposit);  
                    System.out.println(cRecord);             
                }                               
        }


        System.out.println("\nAnother Transaction? (y for yes)");
        repeat = keyboard.next().charAt(0);

    }while(repeat == 'y' || repeat == 'Y');

        //Print the records on screen
    for (int i = 0; i < index; i++)
        System.out.print(anotherArray[i]);

    }
```

Comment: Note for future posting: your code is way too long.  Try to narrow the problem down by eliminating irrelevant parts before posting the code.  This not only will help us find the problem more easily, but might help you find, understand and fix the problem yourself

Comment: My mistake. Ill take care of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is twofold:

First, `balance` istatic, which means it is associated with the class, not any of its instances (objects), or in other terms it is shared between all instances of that class.

Second, as you pointed it out, your static method `withdraw` is accessing `balance`.  The consideration about static applies here just as well -- the method is associated with the class, and cannot access memebers that are non-static.

To solve the second problem, remove static from the `withdraw` declaration (and remove static from `balance` as well.  Thyis will make your code `CustomerRecord.withdraw()` not compile, becuase `withdraw` is now not associated with the class itself, but an instance of it.  So you need to use an instance and call `withdraw` on that

```
cRecord.withdraw(aWithdraw);
```

Similarly for `deposit`

Comment: Thank you very much, that was indeed the problem. Once i removed the static keyword and correctly called withdraw from the instance cRecord all static issues were corrected.

Comment: Now you just need to make sure the behavior is correct as well :) (you have only fixed the syntactic problems (related to what the compiler accepts), not necessarily any other semantic (related to behavior) ones...)

Comment: Actually yea, i am still having problems with my do while loop. For some reason once it loops it stopped working as intended. Initially it works fine and when it asks if i want another transaction and I say yes, it loops back to the body and , prints the first three statements and asks for a pin, where as it is suppose to first ask for the name. Once I enter the pin, it skips the for statement and asks if i want to continue again, this keeps going until i exit the while loop.

Comment: I'm not sure, but it sound like the problem is this: `keyboard.nextInt()`, `nextDouble()`, and `next()` do not consume the newline after the number entered, so the next time you call `keyboard.nextLine()`, it returns an empty string immediately (and does not wait for the user input as the newline is still in the buffer).  Try consuming the rest of the input buffer by calling `keyboad.nexLine()` after the above mentioned three function calls.

Comment: what I did was change the .nextLine() to .next() which seemed to fix the issues I was having with the loop. Thank you very much for all ur help.

Comment: Note that `aName = keyboard.nextLine();` reads in the whole line, which works well if the user enters a full name.  `aName = keyboard.next();` reads in the next token, which only works if the user enters only one word for their name.  -- Your code is asking for a full name.  If you are using `next()`, and the user _does_ enter multiple words, it will throw off your `nextInt()`, etc. calls.

Comment: yea you are right, when i use next() if i write more than a word i get an error. I tried doing what you said here "Try consuming the rest of the input buffer by calling keyboad.nexLine() after the above mentioned three function calls" but I am not sure if I am doing it correctly. I did, aName = keyboard.nextLine();
         System.out.println("Enter Pin");
         aPin = keyboard.nextInt();
            String waste = keyboard.nextLine();

Answer (score 2):

Remove the static from

```
private static double balance
```

and

```
public static void deposit(double aDeposit)
```

and

```
public static void withdraw(double aWithdraw)
```

you don't want them to be static as you are going to call these methods directly from the objects you created, so they will be specific to each `CustomerRecord`.

Then in your code, change these lines:

```
CustomerRecord.deposit(aDeposit);
CustomerRecord.withdraw(aDeposit);
```

by:

```
cRecord.deposit(aDeposit);
cRecord.withdraw(aDeposit);
```

The modifications made now will be applied to each `CustomerRecord` `balance` variable and not to a single `balance` variable (unique for the whole program) as it was the case when it was static.

Comment: When I remove the static from these, that's when I get the error "Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method withdraw(double) from the type CustomerRecord"

Comment: Ah yes I just noticed this as well. Thank you very much for your help.   But for some reason I am still having problems with my do while loop. Once I run the program and do the transactions, i am given the options to choose another option but the program sends me straight to enter pin and once i enter it, it skips everything else and asks if i want to do another transaction :/

Comment: @Batman Well where is `index` coming from? There seems to be some missing code.

Comment: I don't have one, it is set up so that it asked for a y input stored in variable repeat and the while executes as long as the repeat variable at index 0 is y or Y

Comment: @Batman if your code compile, it means that `index` in `for (int i = 0; i < index; i++)` is defined somewhere... (`anotherArray` too)

Comment: Oh sorry, it is defined at the top of my code, i didn't include it here because it wasn't part of the main issue. Its defined completely outside the loop as int index = 4. I fail to see how this would have any barring on the do while loop which is using a boolean condition.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class CustomerRecord implements Serializable
{
    private String name;
    private int pin;
    private int account;
    private double balance;
}

public void deposit(double aDeposit)
{
    balance = balance + aDeposit;
}

public void withdraw(double aWithdraw)
{
    if (balance >= aWithdraw) balance = balance - aWithdraw;
    else System.out.println("Withdraw cannot be negativeegative");
}
```

1. Make `balance` non-static, as you mentioned. This will fix the bug.
2. Make the `CustomerRecord#deposit()` and `#withdraw()` methods non-static as well. This will fix the compile error caused by #1.

Comment: How do i go about making CustomerRecord.deposit() and .withdraw() non-static?

Comment: Nevermind, I have solved the static issues. Thank you. I was using the wrong object name. It should have be cRecord.withdraw and not CustomerRecord.withdraw. Thank you.

Comment: THank you that works. Might you know why the do while loop stops working correctly once it loops back?

Answer (score 1):

You're correct that the problem is that you made things static. None of `balance`, `deposit`, `withdraw` should be static because all of them are things that apply to a particular customer record rather than to all customer records simultaneously.

The fact that your code doesn't work when you don't make them static is related to the way in which you're calling the `withdraw` method: `CustomerRecord.withdraw(aWithdraw)`. Can you see what's wrong with that, now that your attention is drawn to it?

Comment: Ohhh, I was referencing the class and not the object name which was cRecord. I've changed it to cRecord.withdraw(aWithdraw) and that fixed the static issue. Is this what you were alluding too?

Answer (score 1):

In your instance variables for `CustomerRecord` you have `balance` declared as a static variable.

This means that anytime you change `balance` in one instance of the class that it will change in all instances. For example, the deposit and withdraw methods.

I assume you needed to make balance static in order for these two methods to work, but you should just take the static declaration out of all three. Then, you need to change all calls from

```
CustomerRecord.withdraw();
CustomerRecord.deposit();
```

to use an instance of a class rather than just the static class. So,

```
// Whatever values you want here, you seem to have 4 already declared so you can use those
CustomerRecord c = new CustomerRecord("", 0, 0, 0);

c.withdraw();
c.deposit();
```

Comment: I'm sorry but is the 'CustomerRecord c = new CustomerRecord("", 0, 0, 0);' intended to be stated in the for loop? Either way it wouldn't work because CustomerRecord.class has if statements stating that if the arguments do not meet certain values to give an error. So I tried creating the object without any parameters but I still get errors.

Comment: My solution was unclear, I'm sorry. Essentially you need to create an instance of CustomerRecord somewhere using values given to you by the user. Your constructor in CustomerRecord must initialize those instance variables once they are passed through.

Comment: I think that that the perpose of this line here 'CustomerRecord cRecord = anotherArray[i];' but i realized the problem when calling the withdraw and deposit method is that i gave the wrong keyname (cRecord) what I mistakenly did was call the method using the class name (CustomerRecord) and not the object name (cRecord). This fixed my static issues. Now I am trying to figure out why my do while loop is out of control. Thank you for the assistance with the static issues.